# Limit superior may not exist for a bounded sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I know that for bounded sequences of Real numbers, Limit inferior and limit superior exist. But if one takes the space of rational numbers, then bounded sequence may not have limit superior, correct?

I know it is silly, but I just wanted to confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

It is true, take the rational sequence
$$u_0 = 1\qquad u_{n+1} = \frac{u_n}{2} + \frac{1}{u_n}$$
One has $u_n\in [1,2]$ and $u_n$ converges to $\sqrt{2}$ in ${\mathbb{R}}$. Hence it doesn't have a limit superior in ${\mathbb Q}$.